# MVC4 _Layout.cshtml Bundles For Scripts

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, partial-views, asp.net-mvc-4, bundles

In the head section of my _Layout.cshtml page I have this line of code...

```
<script src="@System.Web.Optimization.BundleTable.Bundles.ResolveBundleUrl("~/Scripts/js")"></script>
```

I check the scripts directory and jquery-ui is in there just fine. I'm fairly new to MVC and especially MVC4. I've worked with 3 and I don't believe there was anything to do with Bundles from what I recall, or at least used. From what I get, this bundles up all the scripts into a tightly typed up text format taking out spaces and whatnot. So what I'm assuming is that jquery-ui is going to be added to each page since it's a shared page like a Master Page in Web Forms.

Now in my Index.cshtml file that uses this shared layout page I have at the top.

```
$(function () {
    $('#DateOfBirth').datepicker();
});
```

I've added a partial view with this code as well in my Index.cshtml file.

```
@Html.Partial("_SignUp", Model)
```

The partial view contains the field I'm trying to add it to. Unfortunately, it isn't adding the datepicker to the input field of type=text, and yes, the id="#DateOfBirth" for this field. What's the deal?

Edit: I do get this error - "Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'datepicker'

Comment: Have you retried placing the bundle with the individual scripts to see if the problem lies in the bundling or in your code?

Comment: I did add the jquery ui to the partial view and kept the adding of the datepicker code in the Index.cshtml and it works. This is a fresh project so I didn't bundle anything, it was there by default.

Answer (score 4):

I can't see anything wrong with your code and I am unable to reproduce the problem (ASP.NET MVC 4 Beta). The following works fine for me:

1. Create a new ASP.NET MVC 4 project using the Internet Template
2. Add a view model:

   ```
   public class MyViewModel
   {
       public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
   }
   ```
3. HomeController:

   ```
   public class HomeController : Controller
   {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
           return View(new MyViewModel
           {
               DateOfBirth = DateTime.Now
           });
       }
   }
   ```
4. `Index.cshtml`:

   ```
   @model MyViewModel

   <script type="text/javascript">
   $(function () {
       $('#DateOfBirth').datepicker();
   });
   </script>

   @Html.Partial("_SignUp", Model)
   ```
5. `_SignUp.cshtml`

   ```
   @model MyViewModel
   @Html.EditorFor(x => x.DateOfBirth)
   ```
6. Result:

[image]

So I guess now the question becomes, what did you do differently?

Answer (score 4):

What i see is happening is if I take the javascipt code out of view

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $('#StartDateTime').datepicker();
});
</script>
```

and place it in _Layout.cshtml below the

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery","~/bundles/jqueryui")
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

lines (notice that i had to include the jqUi bundle)  it works FINE!!!

But I want it to work they way i want it to work. so the document ready is fired before the scripts are fully loaded?

UPDATE:
Just surround your script with @section scripts {} and this will be rendered bellow jquery.js file at the bottom of the page.

```
@section scripts {
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {

        // Accordion
        $("#accordion").accordion({ header: "h3", active: 0, fillSpace: false });
        $("#bidTabs").tabs();
        $("#jobTabs").tabs();
        $("#settingsTabs").tabs(); 
    });
</script>
}
```

Comment: FIX>>>>>

just had to surround my js code inside of the view with @section scripts and it will load last after the libraries

Comment: Can you give a code example of what you mean? I'm having the same problem and don't get why the $(document).ready is firing before the scripts are loaded. What is the @section scripts your referring to? Thanks.

Comment: surround your script in the view with this @section scripts
    {} This will make this code block run last after the script libraries like jquery and jquery UI loaded